# which one is correct: "by the end of the day Kyiv's time" or "by the end of the day by Kyiv's time"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which of the following sentences is correct and natural?

> If you make a call using your phone number in the US, you'll be given 10 minutes for 30 hryvnias and you will be able to use the minutes **by the end of the day Kyiv's time**.
>
> If you make a call using your phone number in the US, you'll be given 10 minutes for 30 hryvnias and you will be able to use the minutes **by the end of the day by Kyiv's time**.

Comment: I'd say "by the end of the day in Kyiv time". (AmE)

Comment: *hryvnia = The currency of Ukraine, symbol ₴

Comment: I'd say, "by the end of the day, Kyiv time".